# "SELECT INTO" (or similar) to Remote Database

Tags: mysql

I run a game community (with servers). I have two hosts, the first one is the "community" host which pretty much hosts the website/forums/etc, in the other host I run my game servers, along with a MySQL database containing playerdata.

In short, I want to create a ranking on the website based on the stats in the gameserver database.

In order to not put much strain to the gameservers I was wondering if it's possible (with a Cronjob maybe?, to make it periodically) to create a dump of a specific SELECT query.

However I do not know how to use the SELECT INTO query to select data and insert it between remote servers.

Is there a way to accomplish this or I'm forced to use MySQL's Federated tables?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing, you are talking about is called ETL in the database world (which translates to Extract, Transform, Load). Forget the transform part for now.

You are not forced to anything.... well.. Yeah, you will need a user on the source server which have access to the data you want to transfer and a user on the destination server too.

You can find several ETL tools written in almost all available languages (some of them are cool and working fine, others... not always)

**The 'easiest' (= without extra tools) way to achive your goal is to:**

(aka these are the steps you are looking for)

1. create a separate user on the game (source) server

   - Username: etl (for example)
   - Host: the application (web) server
   - Pass: supersecretstuff
   - Minimum required SELECT privileges (table level if possible)
2. write your extract query
3. create a table on the destination server which structure matches the structure determined by your extract query
4. extract the data using the command line client on the application server (`mysql -h gamesrv.mynet database < my_extract_query.sql > extracted_data.csv` <- this is a tab separated file)
5. use the extracted_data.csv to import the data you need (`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'extracted_data.csv' INTO TABLE myimported data;` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loading-tables.html)

To implement an incremental extract-load process, you can use timestamps or the ID-s (in case of some kind of monoton ID generation such as the auto_increment in mysql) in the tables to extract to determine point from where you should continue the copy process.

For actual recommendations or solutions, you have to know your data, but the basics are these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Question, the table structure on the destination must match the source table or could just match the extract query? (to avoid extracting otherwise useless data)

Comment: Match the query. Quote: "structure determined by your extract query"

Comment: I'm so blind! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer. But I think you're looking to automate this process (cron job).

You could create a cron job on your application server (web) that periodically checks for updates from the game db and updates its own db.

Comment: Of course, you have to 'automate' it using some kind of scheduler or anything else available to automatically execute the steps 4 and 5. My answer contains the things what the OP should or probably want to automate.